# Yank non-consecutive lines into the register?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, register

I'm surprised this hasn't been asked yet, but how do I copy non-consecutive lines into the buffer at once?

For example, let's say my file looks like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

What commands can I use to copy lines 1, 3, and 5 at once? Therefore, when I pasted at the end of the file, it'd look like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
1
3
5
```

Comment: "I'm surprised this hasn't been asked yet". I've heard/read this question hundreds of times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "append" to a register when you yank or delete by using its uppercase name, so `"Ayy` yanks the line into the `a` register, but keeps the old contents, too. A quick way to empty a register is `qaq`, which starts recoding in `a` and then stops without adding anything.

So `qaq`, then `3G"Ayy` or `:5yank A` would continue to append lines to the `a` register which you can later paste like `"ap` or `:$put a`.

If your lines share a common pattern, you can use

```
:global/pat/yank A
```

to yank them all in a single command (again, prefixed by `qaq` as needed to clear the register).

If the only goal is "copy to end of buffer," using `:t$` (equivalent to `:copy $`) is probably easier.

Comment: Thank you; this was actually the solution I was looking for. Appending to a register seems like it could be very useful to me going forward!

Answer (score 2):

If you can only reference those lines by their number, then there is no built-in, *dedicated* command for that.

But something like this:

```
:1t$|3t$|5t$
```

doesn't strike me as particularly hard or slow.

This variant:

```
:t$<CR>
:3@:|5@
```

is not too bad either, if less intuitive, IMO.

If you can reference those lines by a search pattern, then you can use `:help :g`:

```
:g/<pattern>/t$
```

With your sample:

```
:g/^[135]$/t$
```

Did you consider looking for an existing plugin?

Comment: Don’t forget you could also yank-append to a register if need be (_e.g._, `qaq:g/pat/y A`)

Comment: I did not consider any plugins; I figured that if there wasn't an easy way to append to the register or mass-copy specific lines it wasn't really worth pursuing. Thanks for your response -- what exactly does the pipe character do your first suggestion?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble That would be pointless in this case. `:t` does the job more intuitively, efficiently, and without polluting registers.

Comment: @qotsa42 see `:help :bar`.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I can't get that command to work; is that supposed to be a macro?

Comment: @romainl it does, unless you need the text in a register for some purpose… the question explicitly mentions "copying."

Comment: @qotsa42 I'll post an answer.