# Copying non-consecutive selected lines in visual mode

Tags: cut-copy-paste, visual-mode

Basically I want to select and copy a bunch of non-sequential lines (some lines only partially) from different locations of a code, in a way that each yanked line is appended to clipboard register so that I can paste them all in another file. Everything in visual mode. It is possible to append to a register like
`"Myy` and then pasting by `"pm` but it is in command mode and we cannot copy a line partially.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @romainl Well, I usually yank several lines by "V" then "y" and paste them by "p". But in this scenario the lines are not one after each other. and I have no idea how to copy them all.

Comment: @romainl yes I can use "Myy and "mp for appending to M register. But I think it is not done in visual mode.

Comment: Why do you think that? `v"My` does what you want.

Comment: @romainlExactly! I did not know that it would be possible to use this command in visual mode. Thank you!

Comment: You are unclear regarding to what mode you are in. Also, you seem to be asking how to use command x from mode y.

Comment: Related: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/39922/yank-non-consecutive-lines-into-the-register

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use another register (e.g. `a`) and the append to clipboard syntax (using the `A` register)

To copy your first block you use it normally: `"ay`

To copy the following blocks you append to that clipboard: `"Ay`

These commands also work in visual mode: `v"ay` and `v"Ay`, respectively.

To paste it in another file you use it normally: `"ap`